# Can I use Regex in the URL Redirect section in Magentos backend?

Tags: url, redirect, regex

Can I use Regex in the URL Redirect section in Magentos backend? Or any wildcards?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know you cannot do that.
The rewrites are processed in `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::rewrite` method.
I didn't find anything in there that could handle a regex.
To simplify what that method does: It takes the current url, checks if there is a record in the `core_url_rewrite` table with the `request_path` matching the current url and redirects (in browser or internally) to the `target_path` then restarts the process until there is no matching value in that table or until you reach 100 redirects.
If you don't reach 100 redirects, the last url you get as a target path is handled by the rest of the routers: it checks if the url key matches any cms page identifier or it maps to this format `module/controller/action`.

But I think you can write you own router that can handle regex.
Inchoo provides (as always) a great [tutorial on how to create your own router](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/)